# Skyrim-maids:2 deception reset dungeon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have attained both lexicons for the legacy bastion foyer room, however the lexicon recepticals did not load in. I was wondering if there was a command to help me reset that room.